# magento 1.9.3.3 checkout page shipping information step, the continue button not working

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I am developping magento 1.9.3.3 on WAMP server, but when i try to purchase a demo product(from magento sample data), the continue button on shipping information step of checkout page is not working, I cannot continue to the shipping method step, anyone can give me some help?

Comment: The error shows in console is:  Failed to load   resource: http://localhost/magento/checkout/onepage/saveShipping/            
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I have a similar issue.